# UIImageView with fixed width: how to set its height to keep its aspect?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, height, aspect-ratio

I have a view where I need to place an `UIImageView`, and I was told to place it inside a rectangle that takes the screen width and its height is smaller than width (fixed size). However, the images I've been given are more or less square `jpeg` images, so the idea is to fill the width of the rectangle that should contain the image and set the height of the image in a way that its aspect ratio is kept. Then, I should be able to let the user scroll the image vertically to see the complete image.

How could I do this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I need to do this for several images that have different sizes, but that should fit the same rectangular area size within the view

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set imageview content mode.

`imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`

This will make sure that the image is displayed by keeping original aspect ratio.

**Edit:**

I think this is what you wanted:

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[picArr objectAtIndex:a]];
double width = originalImage.size.width;
double height = originalImage.size.height;
double apect = width/height;

double nHeight = 320.f/ apect;
self.img.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, nHeight);
self.img.center = self.view.center;
self.img.image = originalImage;
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks, but this way what I get is an image that does not fit the screen width, since it adjusts the height to the rectangle where I place the image within...